# Controlling vertical space below a caption placed above a table

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, captions

I'm writing a larger document with several `table`s, the content of which is inline in some cases, and included from external files (created by other programs) in others.

Captions are placed above these tables, not below, and I noticed that when a table's content is included from an external file, there's extra vertical space below it that's not there when the content is inline.

Here is an FMWE (fairly minimal working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{filecontents*}{tabular-external.tex}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule
Stuff goes here \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Inline}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule
Stuff goes here \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Included}
\include{tabular-external.tex}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

I actually *want* the extra vertical space. So a) why isn't it there when the content is inline, and b) what's the best (cleanest) way of getting it?

Comment: The standard classes are set up for captions ***below*** tables. You definitely ***don't*** want `\include`, but rather `\input`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I remembered that one of them was a relic of the past, but mistakenly concluded it was `\input` rather than `\include`.

Comment: Both are useful, but different in application.  `\include` is most useful when paired with `\includeonly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `\include` is definitely not the right tool and you want `\input`.

Why? Because `\include` is meant for bigger chunks of text that can be compiled conditionally. It used to be useful in the olden times when processing a large document took an awful lot of time.

One feature of `\include` is that it issues a `\clearpage` command before doing `\input` and this is the cause for the vertical space, because  `\clearpage` isn't legal in a float.

Maybe LaTeX should warn about the wrong usage of `\include` here, but, honestly, `\include` is something like a relic of the past.

If you replace `\include` with the right command, namely `\input`, the two tables are typeset the same.

[image]

Second problem: the standard classes are set up to have captions ***below*** tables.

You can fix it by loading the `caption` package, that sets the default for captions above tables (and below figures).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-tab.tex}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule
Stuff goes here \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Inline}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule
Stuff goes here \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Included}
\input{\jobname-tab.tex}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]